# Memory leaks AWS S3 SDK PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to download thousands of images from an S3 bucket. I'm using the PHP SDK for AWS S3, but I can't find a way to remove the memory it's using when downloading the images.

```
        $keyname = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

        $bucket = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
        $region = 'eu-west-1';

        $credentials = new Aws\Credentials\Credentials('XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX');

        $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => $region,
            'credentials' => $credentials,
        ]);

        $idDownloadedImages = array();

        do {

            $files = $this->check_new_images();

            if ( !empty( $files ) ) {

                foreach ( $files as $file ) {


                    $UrlMedia = basename( $file->UrlMedia );
                    $pathFile = $pathToPlugin . 'images/' . $UrlMedia;
                    $object = $keyname . $UrlMedia;

                    try {

                        // Get the object.
                        $result = $s3->getObject([
                            'Bucket' => $bucket,
                            'Key'    => $object,
                            'SaveAs' => $pathFile,
                        ]);

                        //gc_collect_cycles();

                        //xdebug_debug_zval('result');

                        $idDownloadedImages[] = $file->idMedia;


                    } catch ( S3Exception $e ) {

                        $errorCode = '(Error Code: ' . $e->getStatusCode() . ') ' . $e->getAwsErrorMessage();


                    }

                    //unset($result);
                    $result['Body']->__destruct();

                }

                $idDownloadedImages = implode( ',', $idDownloadedImages );

                $wpdb->query( 'UPDATE wp_icat_Media
                                SET error=0
                                WHERE idMedia IN (' . $idDownloadedImages .')' );

                $idDownloadedImages = array();

            }

        } while ( $this->check_new_images() );
```

I have tried to force the PHP garbage collector every time I download an image, to do a set() of $result and $idDownloadedImages and even to do $result['Body']->__destruct(), but I still don't know why it stores the images in memory.

Memory is only freed by forcing the gc_collect_cycles() at the end of the script.

Comment: I doubt the PHP SDK is retaining objects in memory when you've called `getObject` with the `SaveAs` option. It will simply stream the objects directly to that file on disk. Do you have evidence of memory leaks, and specifically within the AWS PHP SDK?

Comment: I think what is happening is that until I delete the content of that folder where I am downloading the images, the information of the images remain in the memory, because of the tests I am doing.

I thought about downloading them in blocks of 200 and copying them to another directory and removing them from the directory where I download. At the moment this is the only thing that seems to work.

Comment: I don't see why moving files from one location on disk to another would have any impact on PHP memory usage. Perhaps you could investigate using meminfo to identify the actual memory usage over time? Try to identify leaked objects or cyclic references.

Comment: It is not exactly by moving them, but by copying the file into another directory and then deleting the ones created by the SDK. 

It is as if the information stored in memory, is linked to the image.

About meminfo, I have never used it and do not know how to provide information about it.

Comment: Do you need to do this with PHP? There are several tools out there that will allow you to download large amounts of content from S3 buckets, like S3Browser.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-multipart-upload.html), Amazon recommends calling gc_collect_cycles on the before_upload event.

Here is the sample code:

```
$uploader = new MultipartUploader($client, $source, [
   'bucket' => 'your-bucket',
   'key' => 'your-key',
   'before_upload' => function(\Aws\Command $command) {
      gc_collect_cycles();
   }
]);
```